# Get OpenSSL TLSv1.3 Pre-Master Key from Nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, ssl, openssl, tls1.3

I am logging data on my nginx server and I want to decrypt the HTTPS connections made with the TLSv1.3 protocol. I understand that I need the pre-master key to decrypt the same and I wanted to ask if there is a way to do so. I have tried adding SSLKEYLOGFILE as an environment variable both to my Nginx config file and my bashrc but that doesn't seem to have worked. I also compiled nginx with support for logging SSL keys but it seems like that only supports upto TLSv1.2. I have the private RSA key available although I doubt that would be useful.

TL;DR: I'm on Linux and I want to log pre master key secrets for TLSv1.3 connections. Not through firefox or another browser, but either all SSL connections or ones through Nginx. Thanks!

Comment: TLS1.3 no longer has a premaster secret as such, and has _multiple_ master secrets; see rfc8446 section 7.1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70255814/what-fields-be-expected-in-sslkeylog-file . Yes, decrypting with server RSA privatekey only works for plain-RSA keyexchange which is now rare in lower protocols and gone completely in 1.3. I'm not sure it's ontopic, but if you are specific about how you built/modified nginx someone might be able to help with that. Alternatively do you specifically need 1.3? nginx could be configured to max 1.2, for which you say you have a solution.

Comment: NB You need not only the pre-master *secret* but also the current master *secret*, and from those you can compute the current *session key*, which is what you really need. In TLS <= 1.2.